# preg_split by backslash

Tags: php, regex, escaping, backslash, preg-split

In my PHP code, I have class name with namespace assigned in the string, for example:

```
$my_class_name; // = "Aaa\Bbb\Ccc"; // this is not in source code, just var dump
```

I need just the middle name, 'Bbb' in my case. I tried to use this:

```
$result_array = preg_split("/\\/", $my_class_name);
```

However, it does not work. I need to use tripple backslash in the regexp `"/\\\/"` to make it work. My question is: Why do I need three of them? I have always escaped backslash special function by doubling it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to have a literal backslash in your regex, so you must escape it. But *then* you also want to put it inside a PHP [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), which means that you must escape it once more.

The sequence `\\\/` gets broken down into

- `\\` (*one* literal backslash character) and
- `\/` (a backslash followed by a slash; as per PHP string escaping rules, that is not a valid escape sequence and so is recognized as the pair or character literals `\/`)

*Four* backslashes would also be translated to two backslash characters, so specifying the pattern as the string literal `"/\\\\/"` is equivalent to specifying it as `"/\\\/"`.

But why are you using `preg_split` instead of `explode('\\', $my_class_name)`?

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now. And thanks again for hint, explode is sufficient here.

Comment: For my fellow sub-geniuses, he's saying the answer is `/\\\\/` if you're going to use `preg_split`. For my fellow c# devs, if you're looking for `split`, `explode` is the php equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit of an oddity but you must escape the escapes as the regex gets parsed twice...

try:

```
$result_array = preg_split("/\\\\/", $my_class_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "aa\\bb\\cc";
print_r(preg_split("/\\\\/", $str));
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => aa
    [1] => bb
    [2] => cc
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you need to escape once for the string and one for the regular expression engine